# ajax response is encoded

Tags: jquery, ajax, excel

I make an ajax call as

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'John');
formData.append('company', 'ABC');

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data){
     window.location.href = data.URL;   // data does not have URL attribute.
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
  }
});
```

The server responds with an excel file.

I can see the file in the response headers in the chrome inspector.

If i do a `console.log(jqXHR.responseText)` i can see garbage / encoded data on the console. How do I download this data which is encoded.

[image]

It does not automatically bring the download box as expected.

Comment: Define *encoded*. Can you post a part of `console.log(...)` output?

Comment: What's the `contentType` header value?